# Why am I getting this R6030 Error when i'm constructing a std::string?

Tags: c++, windows, string

Hello all thank you for taking the time to look at my question.
I am having an error during runtime of this program I am making and I have narrowed it down to one l

```
std::string str(id.Description, (sizeof(id.Description)/sizeof(id.Description[0])));
```

Here is the complete function

```
bool isItNvidia()
{
    IDirect3D9* pD3D9 = NULL;
    pD3D9 = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION );
    if(pD3D9)
    {
     UINT dwAdapterCount = pD3D9->GetAdapterCount();
    for( UINT iAdapter = 0; iAdapter < dwAdapterCount; iAdapter++ )
    {
        D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9 id;
        ZeroMemory( &id, sizeof( D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9 ) );
        pD3D9->GetAdapterIdentifier( iAdapter, 0, &id );

    //std::cout<< id.Description<<std::endl;
    /*
    wchar_t wtext[MAX_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER_STRING];
    std::mbstowcs(wtext, id.Description, strlen(id.Description)+1);
    LPWSTR ptr = wtext;
    MessageBox(NULL, ptr, L"nigg", MB_OK);
    */

        std::string str(id.Description, (sizeof(id.Description)/sizeof(id.Description[0])));
        std::string comp="NVIDIA";


        if(str.find(comp) != std::string::npos)
        {
            return true;
            Beep(300, 500);
        } 


    }
}
return false;

pD3D9->Release();
delete pD3D9;
}
```

You'll also need the d3d9.h and d3d9.lib files.

I have no clue why it is doing this
the id.Description is a character array

If someone could help I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: `Description` is of type `char[MAX_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER_STRING]`, there is no need to specify the size of it.

Comment: Nothing in a function gets executed after a `return` statement, so you have some fairly important unreachable code. I'd suggest fixing that before tracking down other errors.

Comment: thanks for the answers but oddly enough it was something to do with the entrypoint configured with the linker. When i commented that line out it worked though.

Comment: i did however change it to just id.description in the string constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because C Runtime (CRT) wasn't initialized properly. Please see here for possible causes of the problem:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ecfyw6c.aspx

Comment: Your answer was the most helpful, I ended up changing the entrypoint on the linker and it worked.

Comment: @user2837329 I'm glad my answer helped you! Please mark the answer as "accepted". Here you can get an idea how to mark it: [http://stackoverflow.com/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 7):

Just initialize the string with `std::string str(id.Description);`

Explanation:

This constructor is probably called and this is not what you want:

```
basic_string( const basic_string& other, 
          size_type pos, 
          size_type count = std::basic_string::npos,
          const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

The `pos` argument will result in a garbage address.